# Aspose: Saving word document as html with external css file

Tags: .net, aspose.words

I'm trying to save a word document as html with a separate css file. The css file is appearing with some classes in but there are still lots of inline styles.

Is there something I'm missing or does Aspose.Words not pull out every style into the css file?

How I'm saving the file:

```
var htmlFilePath = Path.Combine(tempDirPath, "index.html");
document.Save(htmlFilePath, new HtmlSaveOptions()
{
    ImagesFolderAlias = imagesFolderAlias,
    CssStyleSheetType = CssStyleSheetType.Embedded,
    CssStyleSheetFileName = "index.css",
    SaveFormat = SaveFormat.Html
});
```

The css and html output:

```css
/********************************************************************************************************/
/* Styles for C:\Users\henrykeen\AppData\Local\Temp\041EF377706B3ECF1A36745883EF61E15DEAA9DF\index.html */
/* Generated by Aspose.Words for .NET 16.8.0.0                                                          */
/********************************************************************************************************/

body { text-align:justify; font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt }
p { margin:0pt }
table { margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt }
.BalloonText { text-align:justify; font-family:Tahoma; font-size:8pt }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Aspose.Words for .NET 16.8.0.0" />
    <title>Test title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            text-align: justify;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt
        }
        
        p {
            margin: 0pt
        }
        
        table {
            margin-top: 0pt;
            margin-bottom: 0pt
        }
        
        .BalloonText {
            text-align: justify;
            font-family: Tahoma;
            font-size: 8pt
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <p
            style="font-size:7pt"><span style="font-family:Calibri">&#xa0;</span></p>
            <p
                style="font-size:7pt"><span style="font-family:Calibri">&#xa0;</span></p>
                <p><span>blah blah </span><span>blah blah</span><span>blah</span><span>7</span><span>/1</span><span>8</span><span> blah</span></p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CssStyleSheetType.External mode there still can be inline CSS applied to some HTML elements. CssStyleSheetType.External is not supposed to move all CSS to an external file. Only common CSS formatting is factored out into the document style sheet but formatting that is specific to individual HTML elements is applied through inline CSS.

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Comment: Thanks Tahir, that makes sense